# How do I get the text that is chosen by some motion?

Tags: cursor-motions

I'm wanting to write a simple plugin that allows using a motion to choose some text and then processes that text. I'm trying to find out how to get the text that a motion results in. So far I haven't noticed anything under :help functions or :help motions that I might be able to use. I tried going through the source of vim-fireplace, but rapidly got lost.

So does anybody have a simple example or a link to a near trivial plugin that does something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you set [`'operatorfunc'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27operatorfunc%27) to point to the name of a function, then write a mapping that uses the [`g@`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#g%40) command.

The `g@` command will take a motion (in operator-pending mode) and then will call the function set in `'operatorfunc'`, passing it an argument to indicate whether the motion was char-wise or line-wise. Additionally, it will set the `'[` and `']` markers pointing to the start and end of the motion.

See section [Mapping an Operator](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-operator) in Vim help (also accessible through `:help :map-operator`) which will have some more details on that and an example. It will also have pointers to the documentation on `g@` and `'operatorfunc'`.

You might also want to read the [Grep Operator, Part 2](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/33.html) section of the excellent [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/). Actually, you should probably read the whole thing, if Vimscript interests you, but that particular section handles this very specific case of creating a mapping that takes a motion in operator-pending mode.

You might also want to make your mapping work in Visual mode. Both the Vim help and "Learning Vimscript the Hard Way" show examples of writing a function that will work for both, and the appropriate mappings to go along with that.